# ERC1155 : Adding a batchMint function with multiple destination address

Tags: erc-1155

We needed to distribute a **fongible ERC1155 token** to a thousand addresses.

We created for this task a new **batchMint** function simplified here :

```
function batchMint(address[] addresses, id, amount) {
   for (uint i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
     _mint(addresses[i], id , amount, '');
   }
}
```

This function is not working properly.

We managed to make it work the first time with a list a 20 addresses. Then it failed the next 10 times.

Metamask cannot estimate gas fees.

It seems like a wrong approach, but in this case how could you implement such a feature ?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: I don't really know the error details. The status is just "failed" and "reverted". This is an example of such a failed transaction : https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6906d5cac2fd8d4b6e86a7a0a0afb5082ab78317f95feda0bcbd01445f38a851

Comment: can you get your contract verified? it will help us to help you https://etherscan.io/address/0xc719457e528e9983628228e26ee535aacdb208fa#code

Comment: So according to you there is nothing wrong with the code above ? If this method is ok then maybe my problem come from Metamask not having sufficient gas limit ?

Comment: please check the answer I edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any state modifying function in Solidity you need to worry about running out of gas. Loops are notorious gas hogs. Is it possible you're running out of gas before being able to complete it? I don't think you'll be able to mint to thousands of people in one transaction using a for loop. You'll run out of gas way before that. You'd need to split it up into batches or find a more gas efficient approach.

Answer (score 0):

If one of the `addresses` refers to a smart contract, it must implement `IERC1155Receiver.onERC1155Received` and return the acceptance value (`bytes4`).

edit: It seems that the array of `addresses` is not equal to your array of `ids` and `values`, I don't have access to the code, but IMO they should have the same length

the code you shared here is incorrect:

```
function batchMint(address[] addresses, id, amount) {
   for (uint i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
     _mint(addresses[i], id , amount, '');
   }
}
```

id, should be array of `uint[]` and `amount` same
you should then check that address.length == id.length == amount.length

Comment: Addresses are wallets and not smartcontracts.

Comment: I don't see why "ids" and "values" would be necessary arrays. In fact in my real function they are, but it is not required.

Comment: I have no idea what your real function looks like, but I can see that on the tx that fails  it has 55 inputs, I'm only guessing til I don't have the code that you deployed it's really hard find the exact problem